# How to stop screen from lighting up?

Tags: screen, 9.0-pie

Just received a new Motorola E6 phone. It's running Android 9.0.  Any time the phone is bumped, moved, or there is any kind of vibration the screen lights up.  How can I stop it from doing this?

Internet search suggests I should find a "Sneak Peek" option under Settings - Displays, however, this phone does NOT have "Sneak Peek" or anything similar there.  It also does not have an Ambient Display setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was due to a Motorola specific feature *Peek Display*. Disabling that fixed the issue. Tools → Moto  → Peek Display (thanks to OP for correct path -
[Source](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Moto-G6-Moto-G6-Plus-Moto-G6/G6-wont-stop-turning-on-lighting-up/m-p/4583068))

On some other models disabling [Moto Display](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Moto-X4/Screen-wakes-when-moved/m-p/3893085)  may help.